# Python: Remove duplicates and indicate index

Tags: python, indexing, duplicates

Below is the tuple for 3D point group (nine points)

```
f = [[10, 20, 0], 
    [40, 20, 30], 
    [20, 0, 30], 
    [10, 10, 0], 
    [30, 10, 10], 
    [20, 0, 30], 
    [20, 10, 20], 
    [10, 10, 0],
    [20, 0, 30]]
```

Each point corresponds with a certain number (index) indicating the type of point (assumption)

```
ic=[1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1]
```

Hence, the previous tuple could be presented as

```
f = [[10, 20, 0, 1], 
    [40, 20, 30, 2], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [10, 10, 0, 2], 
    [30, 10, 10, 1], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [20, 10, 20, 2], 
    [10, 10, 0, 3],
    [20, 0, 30, 1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
uniq = []
dup = []
count = 0
for i, j, k  in f:
    if not [f.index([i,j,k]),i,j,k] in uniq:
        uniq.append([count,i,j,k])
    else:
        dup.append([count,i,j,k,"duplicate"])
    count += 1
uniq.extend(dup)
print(uniq)

for i,j in enumerate(uniq):
    j.append(ic[j[0]])
print(unique)
```

The result I want to obtain is shown below:

Unique part:

```
index       point         equivalent points    index for same point
  0      [10, 20, 0, 1]           1                   [1]
  1      [40, 20, 30, 2]          1                   [2]
  2      [20, 0, 30, 3]           3                 [3,3,1]
  3      [10, 10, 0, 2]           2                  [2,3]
  4      [30, 10, 10, 1]          1                   [1]
  6      [20, 10, 20, 2]          1                   [2]
```

Duplicate part:

```
index       point         Duplicate or not
  5      [20, 0, 30, 3]       duplicate
  7      [10, 10, 0, 3]       duplicate
  8      [20, 0, 30, 1]       duplicate
```

My code is intended to realize the function of picking the duplicated points out and also indicating its index in the list. In addition, I also need to realize function showing how many equivalent points in my unique part and also the index for these equivalent points.

How can I revise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j in uniq+dup:
    if "duplicate" not in j:
        j += ic[j[0]],f.count(j[1:4]), [ic[j[0]]]
    else:
        j.append(ic[j[0]])    

for i in dup:
    for j in uniq:
        if i[1:4] == j[1:4]:
            j[-1].append(i[-1])

[[5, 20, 0, 30, 'duplicate', 3], [7, 10, 10, 0, 'duplicate', 3], [8, 20, 0, 30, 'duplicate', 1]]

[[0, 10, 20, 0, 1, 1, [1]], [1, 40, 20, 30, 2, 1, [2]], [2, 20, 0, 30, 3, 3, [3, 3, 1]], [3, 10, 10, 0, 2, 2, [2, 3]], [4, 30, 10, 10, 1, 1, [1]], [6, 20, 10, 20, 2, 1, [2]]]
```

This will add the count to each sublist without changing your original structure.

Comment: BTW, could you figure out a method showing all the index for same point referring to the updated post?

Comment: There are three same point for (20,0,30). I want to find their index (3,3,1)

Comment: Each point corresponds with a certain number (index) indicating the type of point (assumption): ic=[1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1]

Comment: Bro, have you come up with an idea?

Comment: @PythonFun, I have edited my answer, if you have a lot of data you might have to change how you have structured the code. This will be fine on smaller data sets but is not very efficient.

Comment: Bro, I really have a huge amount data to process. I hope my final result for uniq just like [20, 0, 30, 3, 3, [3,3,1]]

Comment: yes result is correct. I will give you a few pointers tomorrow on how to use more efficient data structures

Comment: When I run your code, it happens that [2, 20, 0, 30, 3, 3, [3, 'duplicate', 'duplicate']]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55800/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-pythonfun).

Comment: Hi,could you pls have a look at my question named "Python: Count and Remove duplicates in the list of list"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow where you're getting your index points, but here's how I'd count for duplicates. First you need immutable datatypes to count, so change your sublists to real tuples, and use `collections.Counter` to count them:

```
import pprint # do your imports first
import collections


f = [[10, 20, 0], [40, 20, 30], [20, 0, 30], [10, 10, 0], [30, 10, 10], [20, 0, 30], [20, 10, 20], [10, 10, 0], [20, 0, 30]]
t = [tuple(i) for i in f] # we need immutable datatypes to count

counts = collections.Counter(t)
pprint.pprint(counts)
```

prints

```
{(10, 10, 0): 2,
 (10, 20, 0): 1,
 (20, 0, 30): 3,
 (20, 10, 20): 1,
 (30, 10, 10): 1,
 (40, 20, 30): 1}
```

And as you may intuit, `Counter` is just a subclassed `dict`, and has all the normal `dict` methods.

To get your uniques and dupes:

```
uniques = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1]
```

which returns

```
[(10, 20, 0), (30, 10, 10), (40, 20, 30), (20, 10, 20)]
```

and

```
dupes = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v > 1]
```

returns

```
[(20, 0, 30), (10, 10, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I not only need the number of equivalent points, but also need the index for these points.